# Maven Vs Gradel log level issue

Tags: maven, gradle, logging, log4j

We r migrating from Maven to Gradel. found an issue with the log level. Its INFO in properties.

Java code

```
try{
//bellow line is 22
  LOGGER.info("Process Started-----START");
......
//bellow line is 34 
LOGGER.info("Process completed...");
} catch(Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error("error",e.getMessage());
} finally{
  LOGGER.error("Its not error, copy past mistake");
  LOGGER.info("Process completed-----END");
}
```

Maven build Log

```
INFO: 2023-07-07 11:18:46.140 [main] ClassName (22)--Process Started-----START
....
INFO: 2023-07-07 11:22:46.140 [main] ClassName (34)--Process completed...
INFO: 2023-07-07 11:22:46.140 [main] ClassName (39)--Process completed-----END
```

Gradle Build Log

```
    INFO: 2023-07-07 11:18:46.140 [main] ClassName (22)--Process Started-----START
    ....
    INFO: 2023-07-07 11:22:46.140 [main] ClassName (34)--Process completed...
   ERROR:2023-07-07 11:22:46.140 [main] ClassName (38)--Its not error, copy past mistake
    2023-07-07 11:22:46.140 [main] ClassName (39)--Process completed-----END
```

How come Gradle printing Error?

Answer (score 0):

If your log level is `INFO`, then you will get `INFO` and anything more severe. I don't know what was happening in Maven, but the result you are getting from Gradle is correct.